# How to scale object positions?

Tags: objects, scale

The answer sadly used an image - how does that work our days?

https://blenderartists.org/forum/archive/index.php/t-246537.html

Comment: The answer used an image, but there is a link there to [View Full Version](https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?246537-How-to-scale-object-positions&s=c8de01c23eb45882c406da3e8c2c4448) where you can see the image too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Click the button to the left of the object origin button. This should make it so the objects move away from each other without affecting the size.

[image]

For Blender 2.8.x it can be found under the *Options* popover above the *3D View*:

[image]

Comment: It seems that this button is no more. Is there a way to do this in Blender 3.0?

Answer (score 2):

Just change the pivot center to 'Individual Origins':
[image]

Shortcuts are '.', 'Alt+.' and 'Strg+.', to change to the most used pivot centers.